# Vim-based file explorer for windows

Tags: filesystems

I have been using `qutebrowser` for a while. And I really like the way it allows me to use the Vim-type keybindings for rapid navigation. So, is there any software or specifically a file explorer for windows that allows me to integrate Vim-based keybindings or it is already based on Vim keybindings for navigating through the files?

Comment: I'm not aware of any GUI like that. There's the TUI `vifm`. Probably need Cygwin to use that on Windows. Or WSL.

Comment: I'm guessing an answer suggesting netrw won't go down too well? ;) If you're trying out vifm, see also [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) and [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn).

Comment: For that matter here's a whole slew of them: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Similar-software (Almost all of them apparently have Vim influenced key bindings to some degree.)

Comment: Is this on-topic? [help/on-topic]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about vim

Comment: I don't think I can migrate this (@statox LMK if I'm just not looking in the right place), but I agree and will close this.

Comment: Software recs belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ not SU, sorry. It's off-topic here.